# Ionic TypeError- Factory.get is not a Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile application with Ionic, but I'm encountering this error

"ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: corporateFactory.get is not a function"

The Get method is a property of angular $resource variables if I'm not mistaken, I've included all the required libraries but the error deosn't seem to go away.

Here's my Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="conFusion">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Home.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Ristorante con Fusion">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations
            <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{dish.label}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
            <img ng-src="{{baseURL+dish.image}}" alt="Uthappizza">
            <h2>{{dish.name}}
             <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Services.js

```
angular.module('conFusion.services',['ngResource'])
        .constant("baseURL","http://localhost:3000/")
  .service('corporateFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource,baseURL) {

            var corpfac = {};

            var leadership = [ data
            ];

            this.getLeader=function(index){

      return $resource(baseURL+"leadership/:id",null,  {'update':{method:'PUT' }});
                };
            // Implement two functions, one named getLeaders,
            // the other named getLeader(index)
            // Remember this is a factory not a service


        }])

.factory('FeedbackFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL) {

    return $resource(baseURL + 'feedback/:id', null, {'update': {method: 'PUT'}});



}]);
```

Controllers.js:

```
angular.module('conFusion.controllers',[])

        .controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', 'corporateFactory','baseURL', function($scope, menuFactory, corporateFactory,baseURL) {
                               $scope.baseURL=baseURL;         
                        $scope.leader = corporateFactory.get({id:3});
                        $scope.showDish = false;
                        $scope.message="Loading ...";
                        $scope.dish = menuFactory.getDishes().get({id:0})
                        .$promise.then(
                            function(response){
                                $scope.dish = response;
                                $scope.showDish = true;
                            },
                            function(response) {
                                $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
                            }
                        );
                        $scope.promotion = menuFactory.getPromotion().get({id:0});

                    }])
```

App.js:

```
angular.module('conFusion', ['ionic', 'conFusion.controllers','conFusion.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/sidebar.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'mainContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'IndexController'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.aboutus', {
      url: '/aboutus',
      views: {
        'mainContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/aboutus.html'
          controller: ''
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.menu', {
      url: '/menu',
      views: {
        'mainContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
          controller: ''
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.dishdetails', {
    url: '/menu/:id',
    views: {
      'mainContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/dishdetail.html',
        controller: ''
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.contactus', {
      url: '/contactus',
      views: {
        'mainContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/contactus.html'
        }
      }
    });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```